# Trying to publish new version of app - "Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built..."

Tags: xamarin.forms, app-store, ipa, visual-studio-mac

First, some informations about the enviroment:
-App built with Xamarin Forms 4.7.0.968.
-Visual Studio for Mac (last version)
-iOS SDK 13.4
-Xcode 12.5 (I've tried also the Xcode 11.4)
-Certificates, Edentifiers and Profiles: All ok.

The problem:
On Visual Studio for Mac I build the project, as **release** for **iPhone** plataform and Archive it for publishing. I click on Sign and Distribute, App Store and Upload. When it saves the IPA on my mac and starts to upload to app store I get an erro: "Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported SDK or version of Xcode..."

I also tried to just save the IPA on the mac and do the upload with the Transporter. But, again the same error, as shown on the image below:

[The Invalid Toolchain error, on Transporter. Is the same message that shows on VS for Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCrKE.png)

I already readed all what I coud on internet.

OBS: The android version went to play store without any problem. And, I can debug the iOS app without problems.

Comment: Are you using a beta version Xcode? If so, try to download a stable version.

Comment: Yes, I did it Kyle. But, still getting the same error.

Comment: Another attempt: develop the app with SDK 14+. Besides, try to report an issue on [Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/).